# Binding json parent-child list to jstree

Tags: jquery, json, list, parent-child, jstree

I have a list of nested objects (parent-child) and I use jstree plugin, to display them hierarchically.

db list:

```
 ID  Name  ParentId

    1   A     NULL
    2   B     NULL
    5   a1    1
    6   b1    2
    9   a11   5
    10  a12   5
    11  b12   6
```

converted list as json with their children:

```
 [{"children":[{"children":[{"children":[],"id":9,"text":"a11","ParentId":5},{"children":[],"id":10,"text":"a12","ParentId":5}],"id":5,"text":"a1","ParentId":1}],"id":1,"text":"A","ParentId":null},{"children":[{"children":[{"children":[],"id":11,"text":"b12","ParentId":6}],"id":6,"text":"b1","ParentId":2}],"id":2,"text":"B","ParentId":null},{"children":[{"children":[],"id":9,"text":"a11","ParentId":5},{"children":[],"id":10,"text":"a12","ParentId":5}],"id":5,"text":"a1","ParentId":1},{"children":[{"children":[],"id":11,"text":"b12","ParentId":6}],"id":6,"text":"b1","ParentId":2},{"children":[],"id":9,"text":"a11","ParentId":5},{"children":[],"id":10,"text":"a12","ParentId":5},{"children":[],"id":11,"text":"b12","ParentId":6}]
```

ajax:

```
  success: function (x) {
     $('#jstree').jstree({
                  'core': {
                        'data': jQuery.parseJSON(x)
                           }
     });  }
```

The problem is when the json objects first load to page, jstree displays all nodes even their childs; in the same level. Only If I expend a parent node, then children come to under their parent properly and disappear from first level. 
Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I recommend you editing your question: neither C# nor your database code is relevant to the problem, which is figuring out why jsTree is not happy with your JS structure.

Comment: @vorou Thanks, but i think c# code is relevant because it creates hierarchical list structure there. And could you be more specific which is figuring out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the structure of your JSON data is in the right format, the assigned 'id' values are not unique. Some of the nodes at the root have the same id as some of the nested children. This creates a conflict within the tree data as jsTree requires unique id's. If you can compute unique id values for nodes throughout your tree, it will work.